# Configure Rsnapshot

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I'm backing up data on a Ubuntu computer to a separate hard drive. Do I need the admin permission to perform rsnapshot?

I'm having following error when do rsnapshot configtest without sudo:

```
ERROR: /etc/rsnapshot.conf on line 28:
ERROR: snapshot_root /media/BACKUP/WORK/ - snapshot_root exists but is not \
         readable 
ERROR: /etc/rsnapshot.conf on line 230:
ERROR: backup /media/sda5/ localhost/ - snapshot_root needs to be defined \
         before backup points
```

Ideally, I want the backup drive to be read only, and rsnapshot should not need the root permission. Here are main lines in configure file:

```
snapshot_root   /media/BACKUP/WORK/
# LOCALHOST
backup  /media/sda5/    localhost/
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but it's fairly easy to solve.

You simply have to change the permissions of the folder you set `rsnapshot` to, to your user:

```
chown USER_NAME:USER_NAME PATH
```

In your case:

```
chown USER_NAME:USER_NAME /media/BACKUP/WORK/
```

However you usually want, that only root is able to make and delete backups
You can however create a cron tab which creates backups automatically